# Regex Space character in Sed

Tags: regex, sed

I've tried almost everything (I guess) but nothing worked. 
(Operating System: Ubuntu 12.04)

Expressions to be matched (removed from text files):

```
a c 4
a k 23
o s 1
```

What I tried:

```
's/[[a-z][:space:][a-z][:space:][0-9]]\{1,\}//gi'
's/.\s.\s[0-9]+//g'
's/[:alpha:][:space:][:alpha:][:space:][:digit:]+'
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This should match:

```
sed 's/[a-z][ ]*[a-z][ ]*[0-9]*//gi'
```

Your 1st try misses a couple of square brackets, and you don't need the outermost one:

```
sed 's/[a-z][[:space:]][a-z][[:space:]][0-9]\{1,\}//gi' input
```

Your 2nd example fails because you need to escape the `+`, and still it will only work in gnu sed:

```
sed 's/.\s.\s[0-9]\+//g' input
```

Also some similar problems with the last one:

```
sed 's/[[:alpha:]][[:space:]][[:alpha:]][[:space:]][[:digit:]]\+//' input
```

Answer (score 2):

The one in the middle is *close*! You have to escape the plus sign for a reason that is beyond me.
I also replaced the dot "`.`" with "`[a-z]`" so it only matches letters.

```
sed 's/[a-z]\s[a-z]\s[0-9]\+//g'
```

Bonus portable version for older `sed`-Versions (Hello, Mac users!). Some `sed` implementations are picky on the "`+`" :

```
sed 's/[a-z]\s[a-z]\s[0-9][0-9]*//g'
```

Answer (score 1):

`[...]` defines a character class. `[a-z]` matches any character from `a` to `z`. To match consecutive characters, you have to use a class for each: `[a-z][[:space:]][a-z]`.

For `+` to have the special meaning, you have to backslash it: `[0-9]\+`.

Named character classes only work inside character classes, i.e. `[[:alpha:]][[:space:]]`.